# Printing an object from json in js

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous

I have some info in JSON form fetched from my API, now I want to console.log a specific object from it, I have tried a few ways, but I get either undefined or the whole JSON text printed out
The code I have right now:

```
const api_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/';

async function getapi(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

getapi(api_url);

var results = getapi(api_url);

console.log(results);
```

I just started working with apis and async js I would love to get some help.

Comment: What does the JSON typically look like? Post it an example.

Comment: maybe in you method return JSON.parse(data); so it would be a js object and not json string?

Comment: `getapi` will return a promise (it's an async function, and they always return promises) so `results` will probably be `Promise <pending>`. You can't log `results` immediately from it.

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log` is running at compile time, so in order to handle a synchronous function, you need to do something like:

```js
const api_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/';

async function getapi(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

getapi(api_url).then(res => console.log(res));
```

The `then` tells the compiler to wait for the `async` function to return a value, similarly to how `await` in the function is waiting for the response to return from the server.

Answer (score 0):

`async` functions will always return a promise. [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) returns a promise. Even `.json()` will return one. So just return the parsed data from the function, `await` that, and then log the data.

[Here's the useful MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

```js
const api_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/';

async function getapi(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  return response.json();
}

async function main() {
  const data = await getapi(api_url);
  console.log(data);
}

main();
```